# Can't start programs from batch file. Windows cannot find the file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I'm trying to start multiple programs simultaneously, and I have a batch file with this command

```
Start "My Program" "E:\Path1A\Path1B\Program1.exe"
Start "My Program Also" "E:\Path1A\Path2A\Path2B\Program2.exe" options"
```

Windows pop up that say:

```
Windows cannot find 'E:\Path1A\Path1B\Program1.exe' Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

Windows cannot find 'E:\Path1A\Path2A\Path2B\Program2.exe' Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

This is running on Windows 8.1. I double checked the path, and it's correct. What's going on here?

Comment: `.exe`, not `.exe.` (note the removal of the trailing `.`).

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I just edited the question. The batch file doesn't have the periods. @MarcB

Comment: Are you sure it's an `.exe` file? Windows hides extensions of known file types by default, so maybe you accidentally named it `Program.exe.bat` or something.

Comment: @Adam Yep. I have Windows set not to hide extensions, so I'm sure it can't be exe.exe.

Comment: The second path is really a problem because your options must go after the quoted path and not inside the quotes.  I don't know what's wrong with the first one.  I'd start with in the batch file doing `if not exist "E:\...\Program1.exe" echo fail`.  If that prints "fail", then your path is wrong.

Comment: Your files aren't in that location with that filename.  That is what that specific error message is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below

```
START "My Program" /D "E:\Path1A\Path1B\" Program1.exe
START "My Program Also" /D "E:\Path1A\Path2A\Path2B\" Program2.exe "options"
```

Answer (score 0):

try without `start`. Like this :

```
"E:\Path1A\Path1B\Program1.exe"
"E:\Path1A\Path2A\Path2B\Program2.exe" options
```

Comment: It results with this:

    'E:\Path1A\Path1B\Program1.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable, or batchfile.
    'E:\Path1A\Path2A\Path2B\Program2.exe options' the system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: That boils it down to - the first has some problem with the file name and the second has an issue with the path (path2A\path2B).         From this comment it seems that you didn't surround with quotes - does it contain spaces?

Comment: @IrRelevant Yes. the path has spaces. I put the quotes around it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your files aren't in that location with that filename. That is what that specific error message is telling you;

If there are non-latin characters in the path or filename then they can be the issue.

Additionally you have unbalanced double quotes in this line:

```
Start "My Program Also" "E:\Path1A\Path2A\Path2B\Program2.exe" options"
```